# Trouble running statrup script on Linux

Tags: linux, tomcat, startup, registerstartupscript

I'm using the Amazon flavor of Linux

```
uname -a
Linux mydomain.org 3.19.25-82.99.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Dec 3 21:29:43 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and I want to run the following script upon system reboot ...

```
ls -al /home/davea/install/apache-tomcat-6.0.35/bin/startup.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 davea mycompany 2023 Nov 28  2011 /home/davea/install/apache-tomcat-6.0.35/bin/startup.sh
```

So I created this file,

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 73 Dec 10 19:29 /etc/init.d/start_tomcat
```

with the lines

```
#!/bin/sh

sh /home/davea/install/apache-tomcat-6.0.35/bin/startup.sh
```

However, when I reboot my system, this script isn't getting invoked.  What steps have I left out?  I can run the script fine at a command line when I'm logged in.

**Edit:** Also, I created this symlink in /etc/rc.d ...

```
ls -al /etc/rc.d/start_tomcat
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Dec 10 19:29 /etc/rc.d/start_tomcat -> /etc/init.d/start_tomcat
```

Still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the start-up script under `init.d` to your default runlevel.

```
sudo update-rc.d /etc/init.d/start_tomcat defaults
```

Which should create symlinks to your script under the appropriate `/etc/rc?.d` folder(s).

Comment: Where does update-rc.d live?  When I try the command you listed, I get a "sudo: update-rc.d: command not found" error.

Comment: @DaveA It's `/usr/sbin/update-rc.d` here. As I said, all that script does is create symlinks under /etc/rc?.d

Comment: Even thouhg I don't have a /usr/sbin/update-rc.d file, I created a symlink (see my edit).  Unfortunately, same result (script isn't run and server isn't started)

Comment: Great now create one under the correct run-level. Go read "/etc/init.d/README"; I have the default-start levels as 2,3,4 and 5. So you need your links under `/etc/rc2.d`, `/etc/rc3.d`, `/etc/rc4.d` and `/etc/rc5.d`. Also, you should link for stopping under 0, 1 and 6.

Comment: I did exactly as you said but no luck.  I sense there is somethign going on beyond what I"ve told you and that your answer is correct, but I'm going to troubleshoot that first before I accept.  Thanks, - Dave

Comment: You could try edited `/etc/rc.local`. Place the call to `/home/davea/install/apache-tomcat-6.0.35/bin/startup.sh` there (before `exit 0`), and then `chmod +x /etc/rc.local` and it should start for you.

Comment: Ok this mostly works but the catch is you have to name the start scripts something starting with "S##", so I named mine "S45start_tomcat" and teh stop scripts ahve to start with a "K" -- e.g. "K50stop_tomcat".

Answer (score 0):

This depends on which startup program is being used. Assuming you have privileges to do so, and if the star up program is the chkconfig program your etc/init.d/start script must follow suit in that you need such header fields like:

```
   # chkconfig: <levels> <start> <stop>
   # description: <some description>
```

For other programs, like systemctl (redhat/fedora) you'll need to create a file with directives in it in the following folder:

```
  /etc/systemd/system/
```

You'd typically make a file called serviceName.service with the following entries:

```
[Unit]
Description=MyApp

[Service]

ExecStart=/path/to/myService/executable.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then run:

```
sudo systemctl enable /etc/systemd/system/hello.service
sudo systemctl start hello.service
```

If this is a LSB (Linux Standards Based) OS/Startup you should follow the tutorial below:

https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts